# What is the difference between Driver and Webdriver (python selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, driver, seleniumbase

About Selenium with Python... What is the difference between `from seleniumbase import Driver` (seleniumbase) and `from selenium import webdriver` (selenium, seleniumwire)?
What is the difference in "use cases"?

I see only constructor difference: seleniumbase Driver is harder to set options, then manipulaton with object are same.

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
driver = Driver(uc=False, headless=True, proxy=proxy, incognito=None, user_data_dir=None, extension_dir=None, binary_location=None)
```

```py
from selenium import webdriver as Driver
driver = Driver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to compare this:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
driver = Driver()
```

with:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

The seleniumbase `driver` has more methods than the regular selenium one. The seleniumbase driver methods also have auto-selector detection, smart waiting, special assertion methods, allow truncated URLs, and support the `TAG:contains("TEXT")` selector. That means you can do this:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver()
driver.open("seleniumbase.io/simple/login")
driver.type("#username", "demo_user")
driver.type("#password", "secret_pass")
driver.click('a:contains("Sign in")')
driver.assert_exact_text("Welcome!", "h1")
driver.assert_element("img#image1")
driver.highlight("#image1")
driver.click_link("Sign out")
driver.assert_text("signed out", "#top_message")
driver.quit()
```

There are some other differences, such as the way options are passed. SeleniumBase options are passed as args into the `Driver()` definition for the  `Driver()` Manager format (there are many other formats, such as `SB()`, `BaseCase`, etc.)

SeleniumBase also has a UC Mode option, which has special methods for letting your bots bypass CAPTCHAs that block regular Selenium bots:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://top.gg/", 6)
driver.quit()
```

Here's a CAPTCHA-bypass example where clicking is required:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://seleniumbase.io/apps/turnstile", 3)
driver.uc_switch_to_frame("iframe")
driver.uc_click("span.mark")
driver.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```